# How to read source code of exploits in Metasploit?

Tags: directory, metasploit

As I said in the question header, how can I read or access the source codes of exploits in Metasploit on Kali?

Note: Please, don't say "did you look under ~/.msf4". Because there is no anything except empty folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure ~/.msf4 should only mainly contain user custom settings, as it usually is for hidden folders under the Linux user home directory.

The framework files are in the following folder:

```
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/
```

I don't know which version you're using, just type this to find it:

```
    cd /usr/share/metasploit*
```

Comment: Also installation folder of metasploit can vary from systems to systems or metasploit versions to its versions. So we can use the following command in terminal to find metasploit framework installation folder: find / -name "metasploit" -print

Answer (score 7):

In **msfconsole**:

```
use exploit/linux/ftp/proftp_sreplace
edit
```

or search for the appropriate module in `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/` or wherever you installed metasploit.